# Disable jboss server log files

Tags: java, linux, jboss, server, jboss6.x

I have using simple web application which is hosted in Linux VM on jboss-eap-6.2. Application works fine.

Since My VM is containing very small amount of space I was trying reduce unnecessary log files. For me info log is very much sufficient and 
You see there will be always server logs will be inherited automatically when server starts up. Here as follow in server path :

```
opt/gnrtestbed/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/log>
-rw-r--r-- 1 gnrtb gnrtestbed     1864 Mar  7 07:40 gc.log.0.current
-rw-r--r-- 1 gnrtb gnrtestbed 14770464 Mar  7 07:40 server.log
```

so on so 
And I don’t want any log details like console, boot,...etc.

I want to control the jboss log server in manner that I can only produce the log which I want.. For me just info which logged/coded  in application is more than enough since its very small application

I have searched long in online and many suggested to disable the logs like below through add these lines to standalone.xml or domain.xml:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment" value="false"/>
</system-properties>
```

This above is also not helping. After adding this lines unable to start the server and end up in errors 
so on so

And also, I have tried all the commenting stuffs inside of logging.properties file under path :

```
/opt/gnrtestbed/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/configuration>
```

But I couldn’t stop the console,.. server logs… its just keep pouring...
Please let me know what I am missing or what I have to do further to avoid default server logs. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

For your detailed understanding let me share my logging properties file as follow :

```
# Note this file has been generated and will be overwritten if a
# logging subsystem has been defined in the XML configuration.
# Additional loggers to configure (the root logger is always configured)
loggers=sun.rmi,jacorb,org.jboss.as.config,jacorb.config,org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler,com.arjuna,System.out
logger.level=TRACE
logger.handlers=FILE,CONSOLE
logger.sun.rmi.level=WARN
logger.sun.rmi.useParentHandlers=true
logger.jacorb.level=WARN
logger.jacorb.useParentHandlers=true
logger.org.jboss.as.config.level=DEBUG
logger.org.jboss.as.config.useParentHandlers=true
logger.jacorb.config.level=ERROR
logger.jacorb.config.useParentHandlers=true
logger.org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.level=WARN
logger.org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.useParentHandlers=true
logger.com.arjuna.level=WARN
logger.com.arjuna.useParentHandlers=true
logger.System.out.level=WARN
logger.System.out.useParentHandlers=true
handler.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
handler.CONSOLE.level=WARN
handler.CONSOLE.formatter=CONSOLE
handler.CONSOLE.properties=enabled,autoFlush,target
handler.CONSOLE.enabled=true
handler.CONSOLE.autoFlush=true
handler.CONSOLE.target=SYSTEM_OUT
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=ALL
handler.FILE.formatter=FILE
handler.FILE.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,suffix,fileName
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.enabled=true
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.fileName=/opt/gnrtestbed/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/log/server.log
formatter.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.CONSOLE.properties=pattern
formatter.CONSOLE.constructorProperties=pattern
formatter.CONSOLE.pattern=%K{level}%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n
formatter.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.FILE.properties=pattern
formatter.FILE.constructorProperties=pattern
formatter.FILE.pattern=%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n
```

Comment: Hi All, I was going through online and I found by below link and its stays no solution for this issue. is it?? anyone please confirm this:   http://lea-ka.blogspot.com/2011/12/assorted-facts-about-jboss-fact-4-per.html